# mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64') in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-ffi

Executing `dart run ffigen` got the following error:

```
Unhandled exception:
Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library '/Users/bruce/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/libclang.dylib': dlopen(/Users/bruce/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/libclang.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/bruce/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/libclang.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/Users/bruce/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1_1/lib/libclang.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
#0      _open (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:12:43)
#1      new DynamicLibrary.open (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:23:12)
#2      initializeGlobals (package:ffigen/src/header_parser/data.dart:41:33)
#3      initParser (package:ffigen/src/header_parser/parser.dart:48:3)
#4      parse (package:ffigen/src/header_parser/parser.dart:22:3)
#5      main (package:ffigen/src/executables/ffigen.dart:54:19)
#6      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:295:32)
#7      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

I checked my Flutter environment:

```
❯ file /Users/bruce/dev_tools/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart
/Users/bruce/dev_tools/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

When I run `brew install llvm` to install llvm, what I get is a library for arm64, which I think is causing the error:

```
❯ lipo -info /Users/bruce/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1_1/lib/libclang.dylib
Non-fat file: /Users/bruce/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1_1/lib/libclang.dylib is architecture: arm64
```

It seems that the Flutter SDK does not have a version for Apple Silicon, so how to solve this problem?

```
❯ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.3 21E230 darwin-arm, locale
    zh-Hans-CN)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /Users/bruce/dev_tools/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (4 months ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1
    • Pub download mirror http://10.141.64.130:8080

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/bruce/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
```

I tried installing the Dart SDK for the Arm platform, but it still didn't work, using the standalone Dart environment, I get the following error:

```
❯ /Users/bruce/dev_tools/dart/bin/dart run ffigen
The Flutter SDK is not available.
#0      BoundSdkSource.getDirectory (package:pub/src/source/sdk.dart:125:7)
#1      SystemCache.load (package:pub/src/system_cache.dart:113:52)
#2      Entrypoint._assertLockFileUpToDate (package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart:599:19)
#3      Entrypoint.assertUpToDate (package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart:525:7)
#4      getExecutableForCommand (package:pub/src/executable.dart:304:16)
#5      RunCommand.run (package:dartdev/src/commands/run.dart:232:32)
#6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:27)
#7      DartdevRunner.runCommand (package:dartdev/dartdev.dart:232:30)
#8      CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:119:25)
#9      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:296:31)
#10     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:119:14)
#11     runDartdev (package:dartdev/dartdev.dart:67:29)
#12     main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/dartdev/bin/dartdev.dart:11:9)
#13     _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:293:32)
#14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

Comment: How old is your Flutter version? Try flutter doctor -v and update question

Comment: To run ffigen you just need the Dart SDK, so consider grabbing 2.16 Arm from here (https://dart.dev/get-dart/archive) and installing it in a separate folder.

Comment: @RichardHeap I updated the problem description, it seems that `ffigen` cannot be executed using the standalone Dart environment.

Comment: It should definitely work without Flutter - just tested it: `D:\source\ffixyz>dart run ffigen --config config.yaml` with `D:\source\ffixyz>dart --version` => `Dart SDK version: 2.16.1 (stable)`

Comment: same question for almost all the python package, why Apple did not test anything?

Answer (score 44):

Running on M1 mac, these two commands solved my problem.

```
$ arch -arm64 brew install llvm

$ sudo gem install ffi
```

Comment:  Thank you `sudo gem install ffi` and reinstalling pods worked for me.

Comment: For some reason my mac m1 is noticeably slower after running these commands. Opening a new iterm terminal went from instant to 30 second+

Comment: Its not working for me. I tried both commands but still having same issue

Comment: Same for me, tried both the command but still not working.

Comment: For those who is using RVM, just do `gem install ffi` without `sudo`. (uninstall the previous install by doing `gem uninstall ffi` before doing so).

Answer (score 7):

Here is the steps that worked for me,

1. Install llvm with homebrew x86_64 version
   `arch -x86_64 /usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew install llvm`
2. Install ffi for x86-64 version
   `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
3. Delete the `pods` directory and `Podfile` in `iOS` directory
4. Invalidate cache and restart `android studio`

Comment: I don't know why there are no upvotes here, this actually worked for me and made total sense. Thanks Sanjay Ishwar

Answer (score 5):

I had passed thought this and it's awful! The problem here is how you installed LLVM, the LLVM itself installed via Home-brew by default as ARM64, but you should had installed the X86_64 version of it. To solve try this:

1. Uninstall current LLVM: `brew uninstall llvm` ss
2. Make sure to have a x86_64 of homebrew installed as showed in [this medium article](https://medium.com/mkdir-awesome/how-to-install-x86-64-homebrew-packages-on-apple-m1-macbook-54ba295230f)
3. Then install with homebrew x86 version: `arch -x86_64 /usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew install llvm`

Then you ffi gen will work.

Answer (score 5):

This error appears on MacBooks with an Apple Silicon M1 chip. The problem appears only when running a command thru Terminal configured to be opened with Rosetta.

What I did as a workaround was to:

1. Clone Terminal application
2. Rename it to "Terminal x86_64"
3. Got info by right click + "Get info"
4. Unchecked "Open with Rosetta"

So, every time I want to run a command that causes this error, I use the "Terminal x86_64" to run it and guess what? It works.

Comment: It still occurs, whether Terminal has the option "open with rosetta" checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem in VS Code, and I tried below instructions, then it worked.

1. open the workspace setting in JSON format and add.

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": { "x86 bash": { "path": "/usr/bin/arch",
"args": [ "-arch", "x86_64", "/bin/bash" ] } },
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "x86 bash"
```

Here is the above code image.

[image: code]

2. then open workspace setting in UI type `defualt profile` in search area than select workspace→terminal then select `X86 bash`

[image: settings]

Answer (score 1):

I got this same import error with uamqp library

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/maheshwaran/Documents/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uamqp/c_uamqp.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/maheshwaran/Documents/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uamqp/c_uamqp.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))

I resolved this import error by running below command:

1. Uninstalling `uamqp` library:

   `pip uninstall uamqp`
2. Setting ARCHFLAGS for arm64 architecture and using no cache so it will download respective library suits arm64 architecture.

   `ARCHFLAGS="-arch arm64" pip install uamqp  --compile --no-cache-dir`

Hope this helps you as well !!

Comment: Perhaps a universal binary `ARCHFLAGS="-arch arm64 -arch arm64e -arch x86_64"` is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

ReInstall Cocoapods from Homebrew (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cocoapods#default) :

```
brew install cocoapods
```

You may need to reinstall Homebrew first

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

this is from their homepage

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Richard Heap's suggestion, I've solved the problem!

As a Flutter project, you can't execute the dart command directly to the project directory, because some cache already exists after executing `flutter pub get`. Clear the package cache first, then execute `dart pub get`, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I downloaded PyCharm, I didn't notice that the Mac version actually has two versions listed, the Intel version and the Apple Silicon version. The website defaulted to the Intel version (pycharm-professional-2022.3.2.dmg). I went back to the site and downloaded the Apple Silicon Version (pycharm-professional-2022.3.2-aarch64.dmg), remove the one I had installed and installed the new version. That fixed my problem. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you see this issue with the Nokogiri `gem` in Rails, remove

```
nokogiri (1.13.6-arm64-darwin)
      racc (~> 1.4)
```

from your Gemfile.lock and do a `bundle install`.