# Has anyone successful used oracledb with Mac M1

Tags: node.js, oracle, apple-m1, node-oracledb

I have 2021 MacBook Pro M1 and I have nodes project where I am trying to use oracledb package and when I run I get the following error message:

*Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(/Users/.../mac_client/instantclient_19_8/libclntsh.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/.../mac_client/instantclient_19_8/libclntsh.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e)))". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help*

I have gone to the site and cannot find instructions on how to resolve my issue.  I have also done several searches and have not found anything.  I am just wondering if anyone in this community has run into this issue and how did you resolve it.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe this will help you https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/avoiding-the-dpi-1047-error-with-nodejs-node-oracledb-5-on-macos-and-windows

Comment: Thank you for the link to the article but I do have this code already in use.  It's an issue with the Apple Silicon vs Intel.

Comment: if it doesn't help, write to the oracle support, they are competent and nice.

Comment: Apparently the trick is that you need to use Intel binary version of Node.js itself and then this can use the Intel Instant Client, all via Rosetta. There are some reports this can be done up to Node.js 14 but maybe there is a different solution for later versions.  Check out the steps in https://gist.github.com/LeZuse/bf838718ff2689c5fc035c5a6825a11c

Comment: After a very long time to research, I succeeded. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882029/mach-o-file-but-is-an-incompatible-architecture-have-arm64-need-x86-64-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With node-oracledb 6.0 you no longer always need Oracle Instant Client - most apps will run without it.  See the [release announcement](https://medium.com/@sharad-chandran/usher-in-a-new-era-with-the-node-oracledb-6-0-pure-javascript-thin-driver-e10e2af693b2).  A simple `npm install oracledb` should immediately lets your apps connect to Oracle Database.

If you do want to use some additional Oracle Database features currently only supported in the non-default 'Thick' mode with Instant Client, you'll currently need to use an Intel Node.js binary.  See [How to Install node-oracledb 5.5 and Oracle Database on Apple M1/M2 Silicon](https://medium.com/oracledevs/how-to-install-node-oracledb-5-5-and-oracle-database-on-apple-m1-m2-silicon-941fccda692f).

Answer (score 0):

In response to the ongoing discussion, I'd like to contribute some insights that might prove beneficial, albeit belatedly.

I'm presently engaged in the development of a sophisticated MEAN stack application, which entails the integration of a cron job mechanism for the purpose of seamlessly interfacing with an OracleDB. It's imperative to note that our database administrators have mandated the utilization of Thick mode for encryption bidirectionally.

While the process of installing the oracledb package via npm serves as a viable solution for those opting for Thin mode, navigating Thick mode necessitates a more intricate approach. This involves acquiring the Oracle DB package directly from its Git repository, in accordance with the comprehensive guidelines outlined in the documentation provided here under Item 2.8.1.

However, I encountered a notable obstacle during this endeavor, particularly concerning the absence of a binary for Macintosh systems equipped with M1 or M2 processors. Consequently, it's essential to underscore that Thick mode functionality is presently unavailable on Apple's M1 and M2 chipsets.

Comment: Thick mode worked for me on M1/2 using https://medium.com/oracledevs/how-to-install-node-oracledb-5-5-and-oracle-database-on-apple-m1-m2-silicon-941fccda692f