# UnsatisfiedLinkError when running sbt scala project

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have this weird error when running sbt scala project:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/Users/user/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna11185077732330192528.tmp, 0x0009): 
tried: '/Users/user/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna11185077732330192528.tmp' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture 
(have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), 
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/user/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna11185077732330192528.tmp' (no such file), 
'/Users/user/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna11185077732330192528.tmp'
 (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

SBT version: 1.7.2.

Scala version: 2.13.8

Java version: 11.0.18

I am using Mac OS 13.3.1 with M1 chip

Comment: You need the native arm module, or take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/q/71882029/6802156

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution with a help of my teammates. I have had wrong version of `sbt-sassify` it was `1.5.1` and it works with `1.5.2.`